# Refering to previous value in a vector with ifelse

Tags: r

I'm new in R programming.

I've a simple question, considering a matrix:

```
A B
0 0
1 0
0 0
0 0
1 0
0 0
```

If 1 occurs in A, I would like to fill B with 1, like this:

```
A B
0 0
1 1
0 1
0 1
1 1
0 1
```

so:

```
b = ifelse(a == 1 | b[-1] == 1,0)
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Try `with(df1, +(cumsum(A)>0))`

Comment: `b[-1]` gives you all the elements in `b` but the first, it does not give you the previous element :)

Comment: yes i don t know how to code for retrieve the previous element of the array. using "lag" does not work

Comment: When you say "fill B with 1" do you mean the rest of column B? Why do you need the previous value?

Comment: because B[3,] should be 1 if b[2,] is 1

Answer (score 0):

If `x` is your matrix:

```
     A B
[1,] 0 0
[2,] 1 0
[3,] 0 0
[4,] 0 0
[5,] 0 0
[6,] 1 0
```

Then you could do this:

```
x[min(which(x[, "A"] == 1)):nrow(x), "B"] <- 1
```

This finds the position of the first occurrence of `1` in column A, then fills column B with `1` from that point onward. It seems from your question that this is what you would like to do.

Comment: Thx for answer. Anyway what i need is not just the first occurence, but something like this: if A = 1 THEN B = 1